# Уникальные значения в каждом столбце запроса

Tags: sql, база-данных, laravel

хотелось бы узнать возможно ли составить запрос так, что бы получить уникальные значения каждого столбца. Существует таблица с опциями товара(шины): высота, ширина, радиус.

На данный момент  код такой (опции хранятся в формате json):

```
$this->model->select(['options->width as width','options->height as height','options->radius as radius'])->distinct()
        ->whereHas('Product', function ($q) { -- тут просто определяю из какой категории
        $q->where('category_id',1);
    })->get();
```

Данный запрос выводит просто уникальные строки в том числе и "80 150 15" и "80 160 17" и  "80 140 16" т.д. Тогда как высота(80) должна фигурировать только один раз вообще. Можно ли получить независимые и уникальные значения ширины, высоты и радиуса в рамках одного запроса? Даже хотя бы с точки зрения обычного sql запроса.

Пробовал добавить что то вроде `->groupBy(['options->width','options->height','options->radius'])`
В разных вариациях, в лучшем случае не меняется ничего, вот сформированные запрос:

```
select distinct "options"->>'width' as "width", "options"->>'height' as "height", "options"->>'radius' as "radius" from "product_options" where exists (select * from "products" where "product_options"."product_id" = "products"."product_id" and "category_id" = 1) group by "options"->>'width', "options"->>'height', "options"->>'radius'
```

[image: пример]

Comment: Можно, но это нереляционно. Т.е. ответ не будет иметь смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Способ с группировкой верный, только поменяйте `->groupBy(['options->width','options->height','options->radius'])` на `->groupBy('width','height','radius')` 
Должно помочь

Comment: Данная строчка в данном случае делает то же что и distinct(), как я понял он групирует в рамках ширины, высоты и радиуса сразу, а не отдельно по каждому. В итоге что после дистинкта, что после групировки остаётся 980 строчек из 2500, тогда как уникальных значений в каждом столбце не больше 20

Comment: Да, в данном случае получается что группировка производится по составному ключу ШхВхР. Если только попробовать сначала сгруппировать только по `width`, а потом можно пройтись по результату методом [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map)

Comment: а вообще какой результат вы ожидаете получить исходя из трех записей которые вы выше привели? ("80 150 15" и "80 160 17" и "80 140 16")

Comment: Дело как раз в том что получатся должно что то вроде отдельной таблицы, не уверен насколько это применимо тут но припоминаю что на чистом sql, очень давно делал что то подобное, на выходе будет 3 строчки но 80, будет только в первой. Так в столбце с высотой будет одна запись а с шириной и высотой по 3, в итоге в одном столбце может быть 10 записей, во втором, 20, в третьем 30 записей. На данный момент я преобразовал всё в массивы и бьюсь об них что бы достать уникальные значения

Comment: Одним простым запросом этого не сделать. Как вариант, разбить на 3 запроса и вытащить уникальные значения через `array_unique`